# Algorithm on n-bit matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix, data-structures, divide-and-conquer

Two function `P1, P2` are given that take input `n-bit x`, and calculate `y1=A1*x, y2=A2*x`. `A1` and `A2` is `n*n` bit matrix. these two functions return n-bit array `y1,y2`. we doesn't know any information about these matrices but know `A1` and `A2` is the same except one slot `(i,j)`. (`i` and `j` are unknown for us). we can call `P1` and `P2` for different value of `x`  and then compare the output of these two function. I want to find that with how many calls we can find `i, j`?

In Short answer our book wrote: `Log n` calls. any hint or idea? thanks to all.

Edit: someone says, at first `x` be a column matrix of "1's". and calculate `y1` and `y2` and find the row that different. then `x` be a matrix that `n/2` up elements be "1's" and n/2 bottom element be "0's". if `y1` and `y2` be equal difference is in `n/2+1` to `n` else be `1` to `n/2`...

Comment: How are the operations + and * defined for bits?

Comment: i think it doesn't important.

Comment: Sure it is, for example if they always return 0 independent of the input you are not able to learn anything about the matrix.

Comment: Dear @Henry, i edit my question, but in book, there is no details.

Comment: @Henry I think the matrices and vectors have to be over Z/2Z.

Comment: Dear @Anonymous, what do u mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in two calls if you could transpose `A1` and `A2`:

You can determine `i` by doing one call an mainly check which entry in `y1` and `y2` differs. That will give you `i`.

Transpose `A1` and `A2`, do same thing, the entry which differs is the index of `j`.

Without transpose: you still do one multiplication to determine `i`. Now, just do a "binary search" where your searching area will be identified by `1` in the entry of your `x` vector.

First step: fill half of `x` vector with `1`, the other with `0`, do the multiplication, check if the entry at index `i` is different, if it isn't, then your `j` is somewhere in the 2nd half, if it is different, then it is in your first half (the one you felt with `1`)

Second step: split one of the selected parts from previous step in two, have one half with `1` and the other with `0`,  repeat same logic until you are left with exactly one entry. That one is the index of your `j`

Since you are splitting always in 2, you will have exactly `log(n)` calls.

```
Determine `i` entry by doing one call. (trivial)
length = n/2
start = 0
while(not found)
    var x[start..start+length) = 1 (0 all otter entries)
    do function calls
    if result1[i] == result2[i]
        start = 0
        length = length/2
    else
        start = length+1
        length = length/2
    if length == 1
        found.
        start is your index j
```

Comment: would you please describe a pseudo code? it's difficult to understand for me? thanks lot.